# Undesired output in C conditional statement

Tags: c, integer, conditional-statements

I have an assignment in class where I need to validate some user input and output different results based on said input. Very basic stuff, but I'm brand new to C, so this is where I'm starting. I thought I was on the right track, but regardless of what integer I input, the terminal prints `Good job!` Here is my code:

**C**

```
printf("How tall should the pyramid be?\n");
int n = GetInt();
if (3 <= n < 23)
{
    printf("Good job!\n");
}
else if (0 < n <= 3)
{
    printf("Well, that's not very impressive is it?\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Please enter a valid number between 1 and 23.\n");
}
```

Now, I have zero experience with C, but I do know some Python and if I were to translate the above code, it works as expected:

**Python**

```
n = input("Enter Number")
if (3 <= n < 23):
    print("Good job!\n")
elif (0 < n <= 3):
    print("Well, that's not very impressive is it?\n")
else:
    print("Please enter a valid number between 1 and 23.\n")
```

Why does this structure work in Python and not C? What should I change so that my C code will print the correct string?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I can see your point about this becoming a common problem. Apologies for the duplicate, I was too vague in my searching.

Comment: It would be hard to search for that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`3 <= n < 23` does not work the way you think it does in C. First, `n` is compared with `3`, then cast to integer, yielding `1` if true or `0` if false. Then `0` (or `1`) is compared to `23`, always yielding true (both are smaller than `23`).

Rewrite it as `3 <= n && n < 23`. Same applies to the other tests.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. All three answers are the same, but you snuck in there first so once my 10 minutes is up, I'll accept your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

```
3 <= n < 23
```

does not do what you think it does
It will do (3 <= n) which will evaluate to something (0 or 1 truth values maybe?) and then compare that to 23

you want

```
3 <= n && n < 23
```

Likewise `0 < n <= 3` becomes `0 < n && n <= 3`

Answer (score 1):

In C, `3 <= n < 23` will either evaluate to `true` or `false`. It is not the condition for checking the range of a number (unlike Python). Change

```
if (3 <= n < 23)
```

to

```
if (3 <= n && n < 23)
```

and

```
else if (0 < n <= 3)
```

to

```
else if (0 < n && n <= 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

3 <= n < 23 is the same as writing (3 <= n) < 23 . The first part returns either 1 if true or 0 if false, turning the comparision to either 0 < 23 or 1 < 23 and therefor always returning true.

In order to achieve what you want you will have to write 3 <= n && n < 23